# Is replacing a driver file enough for X servers even if the files are dynamically linked?

Tags: xorg, drivers

I was installing a new RHEL6 machine. The machine previously had Ubuntu 8.10 and most of the drivers were outdated.

**Problem**

After the installation steps, I restarted the machine. Everything was fine till this point. I had to connect the external backup drive and so I just unplugged the keyboard from USB port and connected it in the backside to accomodate the backup drive. The X server froze and I couldn't do anything other than hard rebooting the machine.

**Analysis Details**

I tried various commands like, `startx`, `system-config-display` but none of them worked. I also tried some other options which am not mentioning as they are irrelevant to my question.

I analysed the logs in the newly installed machine against the logs in a perfectly working machine. After a long analysis of both the logs, I figured that, `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`, had the driver `/usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so` corrupted. I was getting an error in the above line.

So, I had planned to reinstall the entire system again but before doing the same, I decided to replace the file and try once. To my surprise it worked and the **X server** came up fine.

**Question**

So how did just the replacement of file solved the issue? As far as I understand, I see the file is actually dynamically linked to various files and it shouldn't have resolved the issue.

Comment: You should post the log output that lead you to believe the .so was corrupt, and explain where you got something to replace it with.  WRT "I see the file is actually dynamically linked to various files and it shouldn't have resolved the issue", it only takes one corrupt binary to bring down a whole stack.

Comment: @goldilocks, I have the notes in school. I will post it as soon as I get them. :)

Comment: @goldilocks, unfortunately I do not have the error log information with me. If this is still unclear let me know. I will go ahead and close it :)